# would like to return the complete html including table tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

This returns everything inside of the table which it should.

```
alert($('table[width="100%"][cellspacing="0"][cellpadding="10"][border="0"]:eq(0)').html());
```

How would I get the HTML inside the table as well as the actual table tag, in this case

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0">
----html----
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this thread](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-outerhtml-for-jquery):

Add this extension code:

```
$.fn.outer = function(val){
    if(val){
        $(val).insertBefore(this);
        $(this).remove();
    }
    else{ return $("<div>").append($(this).clone()).html(); }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
alert(
    $('table[width="100%"][cellspacing="0"][cellpadding="10"][border="0"]:eq(0)')
    .outer()
);
```

Answer (score 3):

This uses the `outerHTML` property if it exists, otherwise makes a `.clone()`, appends it to a new `<div>` (not on the page), and gets the `.html()` of the div.

```
var table = $('table[width="100%"][cellspacing="0"][cellpadding="10"][border="0"]:eq(0)');

var outerTag = table[0].outerHTML || $('<div/>').append(table.clone()).html();

alert(outerTag);
```

Comment: checking for outerHtml is a nice touch (+1) but I'd still add this to the $.fn prototype

Comment: @seanizer - Yes, making it into a plugin is certainly a convenient way to call it.

Answer (score 2):

What do you plan to do with the HTML?

If you want to put it somewhere else in the DOM then:

```
$('#place-to-put').append($('table[width="100%"][cellspacing="0"][cellpadding="10"][border="0"]:eq(0)'));
```

Comment: Actually this is what I ultimately wanted to do. Thanks for the answer. I should have been more specific. But based on the question I asked it was answered.

Comment: Glad it helped. I figured that was what you were most likely trying to do and took a shortcut!